# iOS: read html files from document directory

Tags: html, ios, nsdocumentdirectory

I have `book` folder in document directory. In this folder there are many html files, css and js. I wish to read each html file one by one from this folder.

How do I read each html file from documents directory in specific order- each html page represents each page of the book.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
- (IBAction)btnRead_click:(id)sender {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSArray *filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];

    NSLog(@"files array %@", filePathsArray);
}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Did you try to use a PageViewController coupled with a UIWebView?

Comment: if you have enumerated the content of folder you can sort the array by name

Comment: @Bigood - Actually I have to do paging on my own using swipe gesture recognizer. I just want to know how to read each html page from the folder in doc directory.

Comment: `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath` takes NSURL and not NSString...

Comment: Do you know the file names and it's loading order ?

Comment: @MidhunMP - yes I know the file names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the file by below way:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
     NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
     NSString *bookDirectoryPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"book"];

    NSArray *fileNamesArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:bookDirectoryPath error:nil];

     for(NSString *fileName in fileNamesArray)
     {
          if([[fileName pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"html"])
          {
               NSError *err = nil;
               NSString *fileNamePath = [bookDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
               NSString *htmlContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:fileNamePath
                                                                 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                                    error:&err];
               NSLog(@"%@",htmlContent);
          }
     }
```

Comment: The css still doesn't gets loaded. How do I load all the css and js files for the html file?

Comment: Give proper paths into your HTML files. They should be relative with the location of HTML file's location.

Comment: paths are properly given because when I run the html page in browser, the css and js are rendered perfectly. Is there any other issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *finalPath = [[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:finalPath]==NO)
    {
       NSLog(@"File Not Found");

    }
    else
    {
        NSData *htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:finalPath];
        [webView loadData:htmlData MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:documentsDirectory isDirectory:YES]];
    }
```

This code will also work if you have any css in the documents directory. And also i would suggest you to use UIPageController with a viewcontroller and a webview.

Comment: In UIPageController you have delegate methods where you could handle the html page that is loaded in the uiwebview. Also if you are using UIPageController ensure to reuse the UIViewController that you add into it, else there are chances that the app might crash because of memory.

Comment: hey I tried your code too, but the css still doesn't gets loaded. How do I load all the css and js files for the html file?

Comment: yes the css folder is inside the `book` folder, which is in document directory

Comment: In that case try this, 
[webView loadData:htmlData MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"book"] isDirectory:YES]];